# Using react-router context push to switch to a new view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What I want to do is a "route GOTO" inside one component that immediately leaves and renders a new view.

I found this pattern on stackoverflow but now cannot locate the post again:

```
ComponentName.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

then, at jump time in a handler:

`this.context.router.push(route(args))`

I have it running but am really confused as to just how it works.